# Election comments locked

Tags: support, status-completed, election

Is it by design that the comments on nomination site is now all of a sudden locked?
Until yesterday it was possible to comment on nominees, but now i cant.

Comment: Are you talking about [this page](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election)? In that case I can confirm I'm experiencing the same behaviour (luckly, I had no need for comments at the moment).

Comment: Given that Javascript errors are being thrown, I don't think it's by design.

Comment: Yes, looking at the page with the Dev Tools shows at last two error - one on the page load and one when the button is clicked.

Comment: Had some time to have a more accurate look to the issue... seems that the jscript handler of the comment button is failing and cannot recover the identifier of the "question" to comment on... Don't seem intentional either. Are we allowed to post a reference to the page javascript code in an answer to help the support staff to find the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope; this indeed wasn't by design, just a plain ol' bug.

Fixed now; sorry about that.

Comment: Only to know, do you have any guidance about my question in the above comment? Can we freely post reference to the site javascript code in order to provide help or further details about an issue or you prefer that we don't post such info on meta?

Comment: Oh, sure! [metase] is full of stuff like that. The issue was pretty clear in this very case, but in general, anything that helps reproducing and fixing bugs (JS error messages, screenshots, etc.) is very welcome.